# What's the translation of "to error" in French?

Tags: traduction, informatique

To error [means](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/error#Verb):

> (computing) To function improperly due to an error, especially accompanied by error message.

E.g.,

> The program errored at line 44.

This could be translated into:

> Le programme a fait une erreur à la ligne 44.

However, is there a French word to directly translate "to error"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Le programme a fait une erreur à la ligne 44.

Presque.

On utilise le verbe « générer ».

> Le programme a généré une erreur à la ligne 44.

Ça se rapproche de *"The program raised an error"*.

Un synonyme:

> Le programme a produit une erreur à la ligne 44.

« produire » s'utiliserait plutôt pour parler d'une erreur qui c'est passé il y a quelque temps (opposé à une erreur qui vient d'arriver).

Le verbe *planter* comme souligné par @jlliagre peut être utilisé si le programme s'arrête à cause de l'erreur (une erreur fatale, « a crash » en anglais).

Comment: une variante : le programme a rencontré une erreur.

Answer (score 4):

A common way to say it colloquially:

> Le programme (se) plante à la ligne 44.

*Se plante* is similar to "crashes* here.

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/planter) **Planter**

> **II. - B. -** [Le sujet désigne une personne] *Emploi absolu, familier.* Heurter brutalement un obstacle et, en particulier, avoir un grave accident (en voiture, en moto, en avion). *Se planter à l'atterrissage. Elle se fait engager comme coursier moto. Un jour, elle se plante et se relève avec une triple fracture du crâne et un sérieux traumatisme* (*Le Nouvel Observateur*, 16 févr. 1976, p.39, col. 2).
> − *Au figuré* Se tromper grossièrement, échouer. *Se planter dans ses prévisions. Je me suis planté à l'ENA* (*Le Point*, 3 oct. 1977, p.104, col. 3). *Laissez tout ça (...). «La gauche s'est plantée, point final»* (*Le Point*, 3 oct. 1977, p.105, col. 3).

We talk about *[plantage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantage)* in this case.

The non-pronominal form (*le programme plante*) is becoming mainstream. See the [OQLF](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8875523)

If the programs doesn't crash but still generates error messages, in addition to what Alexis wrote you might also say :

> *Le programme a sorti une erreur ligne 44.*
> *Le programme a remonté une erreur ligne 44.*
> *Le programme a [beugué/bogué/buggé/bugué](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bugger) ligne 44.*

Comment: Personnellement, je ne mettrais pas le "se" (je suis dev), +1.

Comment: Moi non plus et moi aussi. J'ai mis le *se* entre parenthèses parce que l'expression a pour origine *se planter* mais on l'utilise de moins en moins avec, c'est vrai.

Comment: Accepterais-tu le truc des [télécommunications](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/error#Verb), « être en erreur » ?

Comment: @4469766572736974C3A9 Pourquoi pas mais le sens serait plus nuancé. Un programme pourrait être "en erreur" (ou *sortir des erreurs*, voire *cracher des erreurs*) mais néanmoins continuer à fonctionner correctement.